# Why can't a user talk in a math.SE chatroom if he/she is banned (suspended) on another SE site?

Tags: support, chat, account-suspension

Basically I wanted to ask for an arithmetic book of my interest in [The Root of Math](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13523/the-root-of-math) chatrooom. 
I was not allowed to talk, and when I did the following appeared:
[image]
I am suspended on another SE site, but **not** math.SE! What the heck?! This is really annoying!

> - Is it a bug?
> - If not, what is it's purpose? Someone is suspended on some other totally unrelated SE's site and is allowed to ask questions, post answer, participate in meta, on the current site BUT not allowed to talk in chat. Isn't it weird?

It seem to be a bug for sure. It might be status-by-design or something like that. I don't think it is going to change. Although the suspension will end in 9 days but in future I may get suspended again (and even for a long period) and I'm afraid I will not be allowed to talk in chat rooms. So,

> - If I delete the account where I am blocked, would I be able to talk in chat?

Comment: I'd like to know what is that in this question with which the downvoter does not agree. Does it show zero research effort, or is it unclear, or not useful?

Answer (score 11):

This appears to be just the way things work. The "parent user" of your [chat account](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/96787/user31782) is your physics.SE account, and you are currently suspended from physics.SE.  Because of this conflagration, this means that you are also banned from chat: *all* chatrooms hosted by the chat server.<sup>1</sup>  Had it been your math.SE account that was suspended, then you'd be able to chat, even in the chatrooms associated with math.SE.

There have been feature requests ([one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145235/214632), [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199913/214632)) about this situation, but so far no response from SE.

<sup>1</sup><sub>All chatrooms associated to sites other than meta.SE and SO are hosted by the same server.</sub>

Comment: Would deleting Phys.SE account work?

Comment: @user31782 possibly yes, but why not just change the "parent user" of the chat account to some other site (I think you can do this easily, except if this is frozen while suspended).

Comment: @quid I didn't know about this. I've changed the parent site to Math.SE but I'm still not allowed to talk in chat. I hope after the suspension ends things will get corrected automatically.

Comment: @user31782 actually I think I was too quick in my suggestion. Reading the linked posts, it seems that the suspensions "trickles down" from the parent user to the chat user (if it exists). Once this happens the chat user is "stained" and changing it now does not help as a ban is on the chat user already. Sorry for the confusion. In view of this also account deletion on that site is unlikely to automatically achieve anything. [Had not seen the other answer before writing this.]

Comment: One more reason against the chat system...

Answer (score 7):

I fixed it for you, it requires a moderator to force-refresh your chat profile.

(Note: deleting would not have worked. The unsuspension is pinged over to chat when it happens, IIRC, and if you deleted your Physics while your parent was Physics, it would be even harder to switch it over.)

Comment: Still, I can't chat. It shows the same message, "your account is suspended on the parent site and cannot chat for 8 days".

Comment: @user31782 ah, fixed